# How to update the class constructor when it's bound to a DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have the following class constructor

```
public class BolaInfo
{
 private double massa;
 private double raio;
 private double corX;
 private double corY;
 private double max_x;
 private double min_x;
 private double max_y;
 private double min_y;
 private double teste;
 private double angulo;
 private double velocidade;
 private double velX;
 private double velY;
 private Random rand;
 private Random rand1;

 public BolaInfo()
 {
   this.rand = new Random();
   this.rand1 = new Random();

   MASSA = massa;
   VELOCIDADE = velocidade;
   RAIO = raio;
   CORX = corX;
   CORY = corY;
   ANGULO = angulo;

   ANGULO = (double)(rand.Next(0, 360));

   this.ellips = new Ellipse();
   ELLIPSE = ellips;
   ELLIPSE.SetResourceReference(Ellipse.FillProperty, "BallGrad");
   ELLIPSE.Width = RAIO * 2;
   ELLIPSE.Height = RAIO * 2;

   CORX = rand.Next((int)(RAIO),(int)(650 - RAIO));
   CORY = rand1.Next((int)(RAIO), (int)(440 - RAIO));

   VELOC_X = velX;
   VELOC_X = Math.Cos(angulo * Math.PI / 180);

   VELOC_Y = velY;
   VELOC_Y = Math.Sin(angulo * Math.PI / 180);
  } 

 public double MASSA { get; set; }
 public double RAIO { get; set; }
 public double CORX { get; set; }
 public double CORY { get; set; }
 public double VELOCIDADE { get; set; }
 public double VELOC_X { get; set; }
 public double VELOC_Y { get; set; }
 public double ANGULO { get; set; }
 public Ellipse ELLIPSE { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using a datagrid binded to a list of this class and when I add a new row all looks fine except `ELLIPSE.Width`, `ELLIPSE.Height`, `CORX`, `CORY`, `VELOC_X` and `VELOC_Y`.

The problem is those values are generated by the input in RAIO and acording to the breakpoints it sets its initial value to 0 and doesn't recalculate those values with the new value of it.

I though of calling functions where the datagrid is declared to set those values correctly but I know it wouldn't be the best practice way (in my head at least).

How can I fix this without resorting to that way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just an observation: Instances of the `Random` class are seeded based on the current time, which means instances created in rapid succession will all produce very similar sets of pseudorandom numbers. Instead of creating `Random`s in your constructor, you'll usually want to declare a `private static Random` field on your class with a static initializer, and use that field across all `BolaInfo` instances.

Comment: I know, but so far they aren't producing similar results, tested several times. But thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's hard to tell from your naming conventions, whether you are assigning to attributes or properties. 
You also seem to want to use functions or properties. Showing how you bound `RAIO` to `BolaInfo` would be helpful to. maybe you are looking for the [INotifyPropertyChanged-Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx):

```
public class BolaInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged{
   private double _angulo;
   private double _raio;
   private double? _velocityX;
   public BolaInfo(double initRaio)
   {
      var rand = new Random();
      //just do initialization of class members
      this.angulo = (double)(rand.Next(0, 360));
      this.raio = initRaio;
   }
   public double VelocityX
   {
     get{
        if( _velocityX == null ){
           _velocityX = Math.Cos(this.angulo * Math.PI / 180) + raio;
        }
        return _velocityX.Value;
     }
   }
   //writable property needs a setter
   public double Raio{
     get{ 
       return _raio;
     }
     set{
       if( _raio == value ) return;
       _raio = value;
       _velocityX = null;
       RaisePropertyChanged("Raio");
       RaisePropertyChanged("VelocityX");
     } 
   }
   private void RaisePropertyChanged(String propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```